# Rails 7 is trying to use .deliver instead of deliver_now

Tags: ruby-on-rails, actionmailer

I have this class to send an mail, using rails 7

```
class Mailer < ApplicationMailer
  def initialize(emails)
    super()
    @emails = emails
  end 

  def send()
    mail(
      to: @emails,
      from: 'example@gmail.com' ,
      subject: 'example'
    )
  end
end
```

I want to inject at initialize an Mailer class

```
class MailService 
  
    def initialize(sender:)
      @sender= sender
    end    

    def submit_mail
      @sender.send().deliver_now
      # @sender.send().deliver //work but i need use deliver_now 
    end 
  end
```

i am using like this:

```
mailer = Mailer.new('johndoe@gmail.com')
MailService.submit_mail(sender: mailer)
```

I am getting this error

```
NoMethodError: undefined method `deliver_now' for #<Mail::Message:1026960, Multipart: true ...
Did you mean?  deliver
```

Comment: I think you shouldn't override [`Object#send`](https://docs.ruby-lang.org/en/master/Object.html#method-i-send) this way

Comment: In any part:) But I meant your `Mailer#send`

Answer (score 3):

**Error**

As indicated by the error message `Mail::Message` does not implement `#deliver_now`. This method is implemented in `ActionMailer::MessageDelivery`

**Issue**

You have run into rails magic.

Typical implementation of a Mailer is: (taken from the docs)

```
class NotifierMailer < ApplicationMailer
  def welcome(recipient)
    attachments.inline['photo.png'] = File.read('path/to/photo.png')
    mail(to: recipient, subject: "Here is what we look like")
  end
end
```

When you call `NotifierMailer::welcome` this is actually handled by [method_missing](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/main/actionmailer/lib/action_mailer/base.rb#L627) because `#welcome` is an instance method rather than a class instance method, as might be suggested by the call pattern.

The method missing then returns an [`Actionmailer::MessageDelivery`](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/main/actionmailer/lib/action_mailer/message_delivery.rb) object not an instance of `NotifierMailer` or a `Mail::Message` (as the method body would suggest).

**Resolution**

Redefine your mailer as

```
class Mailer < ApplicationMailer

  def send_email(emails)
    @emails = emails
    mail(
      to: @emails,
      from: 'example@gmail.com' ,
      subject: 'example'
    )
  end
end
```

<sub>**Note**: I changed `send` to `send_email` because  `Object` already defines `send` and that means the `method_missing` would not be invoked.</sub>

Then you could:

A) Use the Mailer the way it was designed (Recommended)

```
Mailer.send_email('johndoe@gmail.com').deliver_now
```

B) Utilize the above to modify your service

```
class MailService 
  
  def initialize(sender:)
    @sender= sender
  end    

  def call(action:, emails: )
    @sender.public_send(action, emails).deliver_now
    # or ActionMailer::MessageDelivery.new(@sender, action, emails)
  end 
end

MailService.new(sender: Mailer).call(action: :send_email, emails: 'johndoe@gmail.com')
```

<sub>Note: your post said you were using `MailService.call(sender: mailer)`; however this would have resulted in a `NoMethodError` of its own since `call` is not a class instance method of `MailService`, so I assumed this was a simple typo</sub>

Comment: May be `send_email` or something like this instead of override core `send` method?

Answer (score 2):

I suggest such way

```rb
class Mailer < ApplicationMailer
  # Do not override Object#send
  def send_email
    # Use parametrized feature
    @emails = params[:emails]

    mail(
      to: @emails,
      from: 'example@gmail.com' ,
      subject: 'example'
    )
  end
end
```

```rb
class MailService
  def initialize(mail:)
    @mail = mail
  end    

  def perform_now
    @mail.deliver_now
  end 

  def perform_later
    @mail.deliver_later
  end 
end
```

```rb
# Prepare mail
mail = Mailer.with(emails: ['user@example.com']).send_email

# Initialize service instance and send prepared mail with deliver_now
MailService.new(mail: mail).perform_now

# ...or deliver_later if needed
MailService.new(mail: mail).perform_later
```